# How to insert a colon between columns in r

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame with three columns

```
chr   start    end
chr1   1111    2222
chr1   3333    4444
```

and so on.
I want a data frame that looks like the one below (with a colon between chr and start columns)

```
chr   start    end     id
chr1   1111    2222    chr1:1111
chr1   3333    4444    chr1:3333
```

and so on. Can you suggest solutions
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `?paste`: it does exactly what you want :)

Comment: Thanks Jealie, worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If your DataFrame is called `df` using paste or paste0 as Jealie mentioned will give you your asked for result.

```
df$id <- paste0(df$char,”:”,df$start)
```